# databricks delta table merge is inserting records despite keys are matching with "WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT" clause

Tags: apache-spark-sql, azure-databricks, delta-lake

I am performing merge operation on databricks delta table as below -

```
spark.sql(""" MERGE INTO <delta table name> deltatbl USING <temp view> source
           ON   deltatbl.col1   =    source.col1
           AND  deltatbl.col2   =    source.col2
           WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT
           (col1,col2) VALUES(source.Col1,source.Col2)  """)
```

Above query is inserting duplicates records despite matching unique keys. How I can achieve an output where only non matching records are inserted. all columns are part of key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can see, one problem could be that what you are inserting has duplicates in it. WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT does not deduplicate records before inserting.

In order to not load duplicates into the table you must deduplicate before running the merge.

You can either do this through the python API:

```
spark.table('{your_view_name_here}').dropDuplicates()
```

Or through the SQL API:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(*)
FROM {your_view_name_here}
```

without any more information that is the best guess I can provide.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to update for existing records:

```
MERGE INTO events
USING updates
ON events.eventId = updates.eventId
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE SET events.data = updates.data
WHEN NOT MATCHED
  THEN INSERT (date, eventId, data) VALUES (date, eventId, data)
```

If you want to Insert for Non existing records only : Update with same value

```
MERGE INTO events
USING updates
ON events.eventId = updates.eventId
WHEN MATCHED THEN
UPDATE SET events.data = events.data
WHEN NOT MATCHED
THEN INSERT (date, eventId, data) VALUES (date, eventId, data)
```

Your case ,

```
MERGE INTO <delta table name> deltatbl USING <temp view> source
       ON   deltatbl.col1   =    source.col1
       AND  deltatbl.col2   =    source.col2
       WHEN MATCHED THEN
         UPDATE SET deltatbl.data = deltatbl.data
       WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT
       (col1,col2) VALUES(source.Col1,source.Col2)
```